# The animation on the child is not creating keyframes

Tags: animation, game-engine, keyframes

Basically, my question is the title. I have a "battle" tank, and am using the "Blender Game" engine to make a simple animation by recording the movements in-game.

When I move it with <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, it creates keyframes, but the movement of the turret (with the mouse) is not creating keyframes. The turret is parented to the hull of the tank, with contains the logic bricks for <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>. I record the animation, moving the hull and the turret, but only the movement of the hull creates keyframes:

[image]

I tried unparenting the turret and simply copying the logic bricks to it so that it moves the same way as the hull, but the turret flies away or disappears when I start the game. I believe this might be some issue with the bounding box, which I'm not sure how to fix as I did not create the tank model myself.

I feel like there is a simple solution to this, but if you anyone needs more information or would like the *.blend* file itself, I'd be glad to share those.